# Why set() is used in this answer

Tags: python, set

Given the participants' score sheet for your University Sports Day, you are required to find the runner-up score. You are given scores. Store them in a list and find the score of the runner-up.
And I have found the following solutions. I am wondering why set() is used here.

```
 n = int(input())
 nums = map(int, input().split())    
 print(sorted(list(set(nums)))[-2])
```

Comment: To remove duplicates.

Comment: Although if the winner and runner up have the *same* score, this will not work.

Comment: To remove duplicate entries. This way the runner-up score is always the second from the last value in the sorted list. If duplicates weren't removed, there could be ties for first place and you'd get one of those instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: it removes *duplicate values*.

A set is a collect that contains a value *at most once*. So you can - given the elements are hashable - use this as a uniqness filter, for example:

```
>>> set([1,4,1,2,5,2])
{1, 2, 4, 5}
```

So although the original list contained `1` and `2` multiple times, in the set, these are stored only once.

Here we can thus use it to obtain the *second largest value* where we *ignore* duplicates.

I do not know however if this satisfies the "problem statement". Since it might be possible that the "winner" and "runner up" have the same score. It thus depends on the "specifics" of the problem specification.

Answer (score 2):

A [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is an unordered and unindexed collection of unique items .
Usually used for removing duplicates from a sequence.

Here in this set is making list of unique in order to find second largest.

Comment: This adds nothing over the existing answer IMO